# Need to add Rows based on cell values and copy pasting data from above and transpose it

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet where raw data is placed. I want to:

1. Add additional rows below based on cell value TOTAL. If Total is 2, Add 1 row below. If Total is 3, Add 2 rows below.
2. After rows addition, need to copy past data from above rows A B and C columns.
3. Transpose the data from E to I next to below added rows.

Requested for help, please!

**Raw File:**
[Raw File Image from Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsNn9.png)

**Required File:**
[Required File Image from Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMuJM.png)

Here is the link of Google Sheet with Sample data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iBndjT6BM-FHC_xzsOLj0lPxtxA3QJ9Mu-60dI92GzY/edit#gid=0

Comment: This can be done with formulas but it gets hard really fast. Would you be open to use Google Apps Script?

Comment: Yes Sure, can you help?

Comment: Small question, have you added `TOTAL QTY` manually to make it more readable? Or is it imported automatically this way?

Comment: Its imported from source data based on query (will be shown as values in columns). I can add Total (SUM) to fit to need to the code/script if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like commented before you can use Google Apps Script to create a custom function that you can use in formulas. In this case it's quite simple:

```js
function group(data) {
  const result = []
  for (let line of data) {
    // The four (4) first columns will be repeated every time so save them
    const start = line.slice(0, 4)

    // Get the list of stocks and remove empty entries
    for (let i = 4; i < line.length; i++) {
      const stock = line[i]

      // If reached an empty cell, go to the next data line
      if (!stock) break;
      
      result.push([...start, stock])
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Basically the formula feeds a 2D array to this function. We iterate line by line and for each stock we make a new row. We return a 2D array with the final data.

Once you have this you can add `=group('RAW FILE'!A2:I)` on the top-left cell where the result is supposed to go (in your example spreadsheet, `A2` on `REQ, FILE`).

Final result:

[image: Result of using the formula]

### References

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets (Google Apps Script guides)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Array.prototype.push() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [Array.prototype.slice() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Spread syntax (...) (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: I don't know how much JavaScript do you know. If you feel like a step-by-step rundown will help you learn, let me know ;)